# Can't use "this" reserve word in private method?

Tags: java, this

Can someone explain why you can't use 'this' in a private method?

Or maybe I'm reading this wrong; it lists a private method and says "Does not work with the this. operator"?

Comment: Never be afraid to post the code that you're having issues with - it will help us to answer the question.

Comment: you can use this in a private method. Post the code as this is probably a different error.

Comment: Please add more meat to your question.

Comment: -1 vote:  you never responded to the comments made, forcing a (lucky) guessed answer. Next time please supply the information requested. Not all of us have psychic powers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - it wasn't pure luck.  This is by far the most common mistake that new programmers make with `this`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to use `this` within a `private static` method.  That is not allowed because:

- `this` refers to the target object, and
- `static` methods have no notion of a target object.

If that doesn't help, then post a code snippet and the exact compilation error message / context.

Comment: Yes, it's a static method as well, thanks!  I was comparing public and private, so it didn't occur to me that it was from something else.

Comment: Psychic powers for the win.

Comment: which is a shame because there are times I would like to use a class object as if it was an ordinary object.

Comment: I'm channelling Jon Skeet :-)

Comment: @BevynQ - its a readability issue.  If `this` in a static method referred to static fields, it would be mightily confusing.  If you need to qualify a reference to a static field you qualify with the class name rather than `this`.  (Referring to a class an "ordinary" object is actually orthogonal to the `this` syntax.)

Answer (score 2):

**-** `static` deals with class, **not** with instances of the class.

**-** `this` **only works with instances of the class**, not with `static` members.

**-** So `this` **within** a `private static` method **won't work**.